# Does array_a contain all elements of array_b

Tags: php, arrays

If this is `$array_b`

```
$array_b = array('red', 'green', 'blue');
```

What's an efficient way to compare it to `$array_a` and get a boolean as to whether `$array_a` contains all elements of the above `$array_b`.

This is the output I'm trying to get to

```
//false, because it's missing the red from `$array_b`
$array_a = array('green', 'blue'); 

//true, because it contains all 3 from `$array_b`
$array_a = array('red', 'green', 'blue');     

//true, because it contains all 3 from `$array_b`
//even though there's an extra orange and cyan
$array_a = array('red', 'green', 'blue', 'orange', 'cyan');
```

What's a good way to do this without nasty nested loops that are hard to keep track of?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (count(array_intersect($array_a, $array_b)) == count($array_b)) {
    ...
}
```

or as function

```
function function_name($array_a, $array_b) {
    return count(array_intersect($array_a, $array_b)) == count($array_b);
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `count(array_intersect($array_a, $array_b)) == count($array_a)`?

Comment: No, I believe this version gives the desired output. Try applying it to the given examples.

Answer (score 2):

```
$boolean = count(array_diff($array_b, $array_a)) == 0 ? true : false;
```

Comment: `count(array_diff($array_b, $array_a)) == 0 ? true : false;` why the ternary operator?

Comment: Why not? It's to make clear the flipping of 0 (false) To true.

Comment: `count(array_diff($array_b, $array_a)) == 0` it's a conditional operation returning boolean. Why make it explicit?

Comment: @AlexanderMP, you mean `count(array_diff($array_b, $array_a))` should be enough?

Comment: `count(array_diff($array_b, $array_a)) == 0` should be enough. It's a boolean result, not integer.

Answer (score 0):

`empty()` is faster than `count()`, and diff is faster than intersect.

```
$diff=array_diff($array_a, $array_b);
if(empty($diff))
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: `empty()` is a language construct that only works on variables.  It will not work (parse error).

Comment: yes, you are correct. Forgot about that. http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php