# find all array elements in another array

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays-

```
$ar = array("a","b","c");
$xy = array("a","b","c","d","e");
```

I have to find out each element in `$ar` in `$xy`. If all elements are in `$xy` then it should return true.

I used `in_array()` but it returns true though one element is found.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at [array_diff()](http://php.net/array_diff)

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP - Check if two array are equal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678959/php-check-if-two-array-are-equal)

Comment: @gordon: That dupe checks for equality which won't work for this question. However a good related one.

Comment: @hakre there is multiple answers to that question. It contains all the OP needs (and could have found in the manual easily if he had bothered to search). A dupe isnt a dupe just for the accepted answer.

Comment: @Gordon: Sure, was just saying. But the premise of the question differs. Find all of one set in another set or compare two sets for equality.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does array_a contain all elements of array_b](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945049/does-array-a-contain-all-elements-of-array-b)

Answer (score 4):

[`array_diff`<sup>*[Docs]*</sup>](http://php.net/array_diff) returns an array containing all the entries from the first array that are not present in any of the other arrays:

```
$return = (bool) count(array_diff($ar, $xy));
```

Comment: no need for the ternary here; guess what count( ... ) > 0 gives you ;)

Comment: it gives me the number of elements in `$ar` which are not in `$xy`

Comment: count( ... ) gives you the number; count( ... ) > 0 gives you a boolean

Comment: @rabudde The evaluation of the `count(...) > 0` already gives you your boolean value. No need for the manual assignment: `$return = (count(array_diff($ar, $xy)) > 0);`

Comment: Just cast. Everything non-0 is true.

Answer (score 2):

You might use [array_intersect](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php)

With some additional code (thanks Brendan):

```
return (count($ar) == count(array_intersect($xy, $ar)));
```

Comment: Good answer but some code would be useful. Maybe: `return (count($ar) == count(array_intersect($xy,$ar)));`?

Answer (score 0):

```
$found = true;
foreach ($ar as $r) {
    if (!in_array($r, $xy)) {
        $found = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function array_equal($ar, $xy) {
  return !array_diff($ar, $xy) && !array_diff($ar, $xy);
}
```

This is how you use it.

```
if(array_equal($ar, $xy) {
  // etc...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function in_array_all($x, $y){

    $true = 0;
    $count = count($x);

    foreach($x as $key => $value){
        if(in_array($value, $y)) $true++;
    }

    return ($true == $count)? true: false;

}

$ar = array("a","b","c"); $xy = array("a","b","c","d","e");

echo in_array_all($ar, $xy);
```